# Call django function on HTML button

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to call a django function on my **Proceed** button and pass the selected value to that function, how can I do that ?

Here's the form:

```
<select id="the-id">
        {% for i in z %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <form method="post" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
             <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Proceed</a>
            <a href="{% url 'employee:products_table' %}" class="btn btn-outline-
        secondary" role="button">Nevermind</a>
        </form>
    </select>
```

views.py

```
def warehouse_details(request):
    queryset = AllotmentDocket.objects.filter(send_from_warehouse = #to be fetched from the form)
    print("queryset is ", queryset)

    return render(request, 'packsapp/employee/allotwarehousedetails.html', {'query': queryset})
```

Urls.py

```
    path('warehouse-details/', warehouse_details, name='warehouse_details'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, fix your HTML. The select needs to be *inside* the form, and have a `name` attribute; and the button needs to be an actual button, not a link styled to look like one.

```html
<form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="the-id" name="my-select">
    {% for i in z %}
        <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Proceed</button>
    <a href="{% url 'employee:products_table' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Nevermind</a>
</form>
```

Now you can get the data in the view using the name:

```
value = request.POST['my-select']
```

(However I would recommend you use Django forms; that will output the select for you and validate the response.)

**Edit** If you want to submit to a different URL to the one that displayed the form in the first place, you need to put it as the form action:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'warehouse_details' %}" novalidate>
```

assuming your URL pattern is named 'warehouse_details'.

Comment: I tried it, the proceed button just refreshes the page, it does not redirect me to the next function.

Comment: Thanks for saving the day!, Can I pass other things from my form to that function too?.. I was thinking of adding a date field in the form and pass it to the function too

Comment: Sure, you can put as many fields in the form as you like. Just remember to give them all `name` attributes and use that name to access the data from the POST dict. But again I would really recommend you look into [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) which take care of building the HTML and validating the submission.